# Reexecute a part of a script in bash

Tags: bash

I have a script which contains 4 parts. 
So when I execute the script, the 4 parts will be installed. This is what I want. But it's possible there need to be an update. Than only 2 parts need to be executed. What's the most efficient way to perform this?

I had something like this but it's redundant:

```
if [ $1 = "-u" ]
then
   #Part1
   #Part2
elsif
   #Part1
   #Part2
   #Part3
   #Part4
fi
```

Is there a better way to define this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have understood you're going to execute Part1 and Part2 in any case. So I would code it this way:

```
#Part1
#Part2
if [ "$1" != "-u" ] ; then
   #Part3
   #Part4
fi
```

or... using bash builtins:

```
#Part1
#Part2
if [[ $1 != "-u" ]] ; then
   #Part3
   #Part4
fi
```